# Counting number of distinct integers.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $p,q,r$ are primes in $pqx,qry,rpz$ within factor $2$ of each other. Then how many distinct integers can $pqx+qry+rpz$ represent if integers $x,y,z$ satisfy $0<x,y,z<(pq)^\alpha,(qr)^\alpha,(rp)^\alpha$ ($\alpha\in(0,1)$)?

Answer (score 0):

For a given $\alpha$ there is no upper bound.  Take $p\lt q \lt r$ very large and almost equal.  You can make $(pq)^\alpha$ as large as you want, and there will be at least $(pq)^\alpha$ integers that can be expressed.  In fact it will be about the cube of that, but this much is easy because you can just fix $x=y=z$ and get this many.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. there are $(pqr)^{2\alpha}$ triples $(x,y,z)$. How many of these lead to distinct sums?  think there are at least two cases here $\alpha<\frac12$ and $\alpha>\frac12$.

Comment: No, I know there are more. I think the exponent should be $3\alpha$ and I think matching sums will be rare, but to say I can choose $p,q,r$ to get as many as I want I don't need that.

Comment: $(pq)^\alpha(qr)^\alpha(rp)^\alpha=(pqr)^{2\alpha}$.